# console.log on intervals in javascript

Tags: javascript, timer, setinterval

I'd like to log a request every 1 or 5 minutes from a heavily requested api, like sampling. I'm curious what this function might look like in javascript? I was thinking some sort of `while` loop with a `setInterval`, but not sure how to write it or if it's the best approach?

**Update:** Based on Afshin's answer

```
let logNext = true
const minute = 60 * 1000
setInterval(() => {
  logNext = true
}, minute)

const logSample = item => {
  if (logNext) {
    logNext = false
    console.info('item', item)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any loops as setInterval is kind of loop itself as it runs for good unless you clear it's handler.

```
let myinterval = setInterval(function() {
  //Call the api
}, 300000);
```

if you want to stop the interval:

```
clearInterval(myinterval);
```

The API call section will fired up every 5 minutes until you call the clearInterval.

I think you are mistaken setInterval with setTimeout which only fired up once.

Comment: I don't have an api call for logging, it's just `console.log` though. Maybe in the interval I would set `logNext = true` and then when it logs I immediately run `logNext = false` ?

Comment: Or you can clear the interval (Call the clearInterval) inside of the setInterval.

Comment: I'll just do the set interval and logNext = true / false thing